# A special notification when questions get edited

Tags: discussion, feature-request, notifications

Often times it happens, that someone answers a question in its original and specific kind. Also often times it happens, that the questioner edits the question when he realizes the given answer(s) is/are correct, but don't answer what the really wanted to know.

The such called *Ninja Edit*.

I propose that there should be a special notification for anyone who posted an answer to a question, which gets edited afterwards.

Comment: Like the one you get when you favorite a question (star icon), in the favorites tab on your user profile?

Comment: @Oded the proposal obviously implies, that no further action on your side (as answerer) should be necessary for that.

Answer (score 2):

My opinion is that, in general, we should address the problems directly and that we should not develop features to patch around the problems instead.

The problem here are clearly ninja edits and not the lack of notification.

Introducing notifications here will *not decrease* the number of ninja edits and possibly result in *more upset answerers*.