# Allow opt-in subscription to a post

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, notifications

Let's add the ability to ***opt-in*** to a notification when a post (question or answer) is 1) Edited, 2) Closed, 3) Reopened, 4) Some combination of those things. I think that single feature would address all of the following related questions and feature requests (some of these are marked as dupes of other questions/requests, in some cases IMHO incorrectly):

- [*Optional notification on an edit to an answer*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97740/optional-notification-on-an-edit-to-an-answer)
  *(marked as dupe of [Notify question OP (and those who marked it a favourite) if an answer has been modified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64692/notify-question-op-and-those-who-marked-it-a-favourite-if-an-answer-has-been-m))*
- [*Is it possible to get an Edit Notification on questions or answers that I up voted?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210474/is-it-possible-to-get-an-edit-notification-on-questions-or-answers-that-i-up-vot)
- [*Is it possible to get an Edit notification on questions that I Vote-to-close?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73341/is-it-possible-to-get-an-edit-notification-on-questions-that-i-vote-to-close)
  *(marked as dupe of the "may be a bit related" question below)*
- [*Notifications when users edit answers*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231204/notifications-when-users-edit-answers)
- [*Notify us when the question has been edited after posting an answer*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2322/notify-us-when-the-question-has-been-edited-after-posting-an-answer)
  *(and its dupe [A special notification when questions get edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185025/a-special-notification-when-questions-get-edited))*
- [*Allow me to get notifications on specific down-voted questions*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165962/allow-me-to-get-notifications-on-specific-down-voted-questions)

And this may be a bit related, but I don't think the OP wanted it to be opt-in:

- [*Notify users of a question they closed being edited or nominated for reopening*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267675/notify-users-of-a-question-they-closed-being-edited-or-nominated-for-reopening)

We'd also need a way to opt out again having opted in.

It's a feature I'd find handy in various situations, such as voting to close a question which looks salvageable through editing, etc.

Fairly simple flow:

1. Click a "watch" link or similar
2. Get a dialog with checkboxes for what to watch
3. Click OK
4. The "watch" link becomes "unwatch" or similar; when clicked you're opted out again after confirmation

This differs from "[favoriting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)" (the star on questions) in these ways:

- Favoriting a question doesn't make you receive notifications when actions occur on that question
- Your list of favorited questions is listed publicly on your profile (I would not want that for this feature)
- The number of people favoriting a question is listed on the question (it wouldn't necessarily be a bad thing if the number of watchers were listed, but I don't see any real benefit to it, either)
- You can't "favorite" an answer

I don't see changing how the "favorites" feature works to support the above; favorites is too mature and already widely-used in its current form.

Comment: In my experience, favorites don't work well for checking for updates to a thread. This feature would work better than those, and there can't be complaints about the number of pings. +1 here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have implemented most of what was requested here in the [follow post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/51) feature.